# Ссылка с данными для авторизации.

Tags: вконтакте

Случилась следующая ситуация. В беседе(Телеграмм) парень разместил ссылку на файл в мэил облако. При переходе по ней я попал по назначению, но в это же время оказался залогинен ВК с его аккаунта! Как?! Я открыл эту ссылку в другом барузере - результат то-же, я оказался залогинен. Паренек(лет 15-ти) явно сделал это не специально. Меня мучает любопытство, каким образом можно получить такую ссылку, тем-более случайно. И что это вообще за механизм.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Теоретически это возможно (например, тот же Telegram поддерживает 4 типа передачи запросов), но скорее похоже просто на глюк VK. Они последний год радикально меняют свою структуру, так что может что просочилось.